# Android Studio efecto de lluvia para juegos

Tags: android, android-studio, screen

Estoy usando esta [librería](https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids) para crear un efecto de lluvia.

Ahora quería identificar cuando la imagen llega al limite de la pantalla para agregar el efecto de choque contra el suelo. ¿ Como podría identificar cuando la imagen llega al final de la pantalla ?. Gracias.

**Mi Clase :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            new ParticleSystem(MainActivity.this, 150, R.drawable.lluvia, 10000)
                    .setSpeedByComponentsRange(0f, 0f, 0.5f, 1f)
                    .setAcceleration(0.00005f, 90)
                    .emitWithGravity(findViewById(R.id.emiter_bottom), Gravity.BOTTOM, 20);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola en tiempo de ejecución lo puedes averiguar así, retornará el Width & Height

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

En un view necesitas hacer algo como esto:

```
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager()
                         .getDefaultDisplay()
                         .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

Si te ha funcionado recuerda darle hacía arriba sino comenta cual fue el resultado para continuar ayudandote.

Saludos!!

**EDICIÓN**

Pensé inicialmente solo necesitabas conocer los limites de la pantalla y claramente me equivoque con lo que necesitabas.

Sobre la librería no tengo ninguna experiencia pero me siento comprometido a apoyarte.

Investigue el código de la librería y no tiene un método que retorne el arreglo de Imagenes, en la librería se llaman "Particles" o particulas. Existe por cada particula una imagen. Pero la clase Particle si retorna el X y Y.

Mira este código de ejemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnDisparar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btnDisparar = findViewById(R.id.btnDisparar);

        btnDisparar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ParticleSystem p = new ParticleSystem(MainActivity.this, 1, R.drawable.ic_drop, 2000);

                p.setSpeedByComponentsRange(0f, 0f, 0.5f, 1f);
                p.setAcceleration(0.00005f, 90);
                p.emitWithGravity(findViewById(R.id.btnDisparar), Gravity.BOTTOM, 1);
                p.addModifier(new ParticleModifier() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(Particle particle, long miliseconds) {
                        float x = particle.mCurrentX;
                        float y = particle.mCurrentY;


                        Log.i("Particle # ", "X = "+ x);
                        Log.i("Particle # ", "Y = "+ y);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

}
```

El Logcat muestra lo siguiente:

```
I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.494 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 282.0
12-04 09:04:02.544 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.544 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 404.7401
12-04 09:04:02.594 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.594 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 527.7302
12-04 09:04:02.644 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.654 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 650.97034
12-04 09:04:02.694 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.704 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 774.46045
12-04 09:04:02.744 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.744 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 898.20056
12-04 09:04:02.804 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.804 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 1022.1907
12-04 09:04:02.854 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.854 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 1146.4308
12-04 09:04:02.904 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.904 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 1270.9209
12-04 09:04:02.954 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:02.954 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 1395.661
12-04 09:04:03.004 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.004 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 1520.6511
12-04 09:04:03.054 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.054 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 1645.8912
12-04 09:04:03.114 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.114 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 1771.3813
12-04 09:04:03.154 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.154 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 1897.1215
12-04 09:04:03.214 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.214 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 2023.1116
12-04 09:04:03.254 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.254 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 2149.3516
12-04 09:04:03.314 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.314 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 2275.8418
12-04 09:04:03.354 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.354 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 2402.5818
12-04 09:04:03.414 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.414 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 2529.572
12-04 09:04:03.454 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.464 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 2656.812
12-04 09:04:03.514 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.514 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 2784.3022
12-04 09:04:03.554 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
12-04 09:04:03.564 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: Y = 2912.0422
12-04 09:04:03.604 20820-21314/com.labs.ejemplolibreriaanimacion I/Particle #: X = 181.0
```

En el código lo que programé básicamente, es que caiga una sola partícula cada segundo.

Como podrás notar X = 181.0 y Y varia y va en aumento hasta que muere y aparece otra partícula con el mismo X.

Lo que te recomiendo es que bajes la librería de GitHub e implementes los métodos necesarios en la clase Particle para definirle limites de "existencia" basados en las propiedades `mCurrentX` y `mCurrentY`, es decir si llega a cierto punto en la pantalla que cambie de animación y luego desaparezca.

Espero haber complementado mejor mi respuesta.

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta. Con esto como puede identificar cuando la imagen llega al final de la pantalla?

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta pero como puedo obtener las coordenadas (x,y) de la imagen?

Comment: Hola @AgustinVal, edite mi respuesta, adjunte como conocer el X y el Y de 1 partícula. Para saber cuando ésta llega al final de la pantalla tienes que implementar sobre la librería una condición donde definas el límite o final de la pantalla y compararla con el mCurrentY de la partícula para hacer lo que tienes pensado hacer. Adicionalmente la librería tiene un arreglo de partículas por lo que pienso implementes sobre la clase Particle, así cada una sabrá que hacer cuando llegue al límite de la pantalla.